# javascript-jquery carousel function error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having an issue with this carousel that I am building with javaScript/jQuery.

I know I could probably find a plugin to do the same thing, but I am fairly new to javaScript and need the practice. Chrome is throwing me an

> Uncaught TypeError: Undefined is not a function

I'm assuming its a syntax error, but I am unable to find it. Chrome claims in on line 42 which is the doc.ready function. What am I doing wrong?

```
    /* carousel
     has a list of items
     if the list size is greater than x, only show n based on screen size
     each list item is composed of an image, title, description and button
     the carousel will have an arrow on the left and right, allowing users to scroll through the list items
     the list should wrap
     the "show" strategy is:
      -- if user clicks right arrow
      ---- get the last visible list item
      ---- check for the existence of a next item
      ---- if there isn't a next item
      ------ moved the first item of the list the then end of the list
      ------ display it
      -- the inverse is also true*/



    function initFeaturedWork() {
    var $work = $('.featuredWork');
    var $pageWrap = $('.page-wrap');
    if ($work && $work.length > 0) {

        if ($work.length <= 3) {
            $work.show();
        } else {
            $.each($work, function(index) {
                if (index < 4)
                    $(this).show();
                else return;
            });

            $pageWrap.before(".backArrow");
            $pageWrap.after(".forwardArrow");

            $(".backArrow").show();
            $(".forwardArrow").show();
        }

    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    initFeaturedWork();
    /*
     * EVENT HANDLERS
     */
    $(document).on('click', '.backArrow', function(e) {
        var $lastWrap = $(this).siblings('.page-wrap').last();
        var $threecolumn = $lastWrap.find('.threecolumn');
        var $first_visible = $threecolumn.filter(':visible').first();
        var $prev = $first_visible.prev();
        var $moveFirst = $threecolumn.last();

        if ($prev && $prev.length > 0) {
            $threecolumn.filter(':visible').last().hide();
            $prev.show();
        } else {
            $lastWrap.prepend(moveFirst);
            moveFirst.show();
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.forwardArrow', function(e) {
        var $firstWrap = $(this).siblings('.page-wrap').first();
        var $threecolumn = $firstWrap.find('.threecolumn');
        var $last_visible = $threecolumn.filter(':visible').last();
        var $next = $last_visible.next();
        var $moveLast = $threecolumn.first();

        if ($next && $next.length > 0) {
            $threecolumn.filter(':visible').first().hide();
            $next.show();
        } else {
            $firstWrap.prepend(moveLast);
            moveLast.show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: That may seem a stupid question, but is jQuery loaded before this script?

Comment: It is loaded but maybe WordPress doesn't like the fact that I hard coded it into the header. I try the wp_enqueue_scripts method and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: I've heard Wordpress override the `$` symbole (i've never used it, hence why i said *I heard*). Try reassign wrapping your script in a scope `(function($){your code})(jQuery)` or manually change all the `$` to `jQuery`.

Comment: Try adding a breakpoint in developer tools in document.ready and step through to see what's null